# ui.router Go to the state based on preresolved parameter

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

Travellers!

Here is the [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/enuneiRgEggwp1lKL09I?p=preview)

What I intended to do was the following.

1. 'page1' - is a default app's landing page. Doesn't work, may be because of plunkr, as real environment works ok for this case.
2. Once I route to 'page2' a resolved 'activeTabId' gets activated automatically and url changes itself from '/page2' into '/page2/2' lets say. I tried it like this

   ```
   $scope.activeTabId = 2; // not resolved but hardcoded instead
   $state.go('root.page2.tab', { tabId: $scope.activeTabId });
   ```

   it doesn't help and breaks everything.

Is there a way to resolve and route into a state without making a user to click the 'tabId' link? Also I assume there might be better solutions for the case, so please let me know.

Thank you

Comment: Having a really hard time understanding your problem.  Your plunkr seems broken as well ... can you try to reword?

Comment: There is link a the header leading me to 'root.page2' state. Before it's controller takes actions we might resolve smth from backend, but for now let's pretend we did so and hardcode a activeTabId value. 
Cant quite get what should be done to get automatically redirected into '/page2/:tabId' when I navigate to '/page2'

Comment: Indeed, I do. Sorry for taking your time

Comment: Good luck with UI-Router sir ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to fix somethings with your fiddle.  Simple things:

```
//$scope.activeTabId = 2; // will be resolved at 'root.page2' state
//$state.go('root.page2.tab', { tabId: $scope.activeTabId });
```

Inside `Page2Controller` I added $state as an injectable things started to work.  Updated [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/P9xREWJSBqupLWY83ZEZ?p=preview)

Once that happened I redirected your root state to `Page1`.  Inside of Page2Controller i added some defaults.

Comment: Right, a dependency... Thank you